# Angular filter not returning from inside an $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and am having trouble figuring out why the following filter isn't returning. The console log is working perfectly, but the characterName never comes back to the view. I know the filter is being called correctly because if I add "return 'foo'" outside the $http then it shows up in the view no problem.

```
app.filter('characterName',['$http', function($http) {
    return function(input) {
      name = "";
      $http.get('/api/character/' + input)
      .success(function (data) {
        name = data.characterName;
        console.log("Name: " + name);
        return name;
      });
    }
}]);
```

and in the view:
    `<p>Character : {{item.character | characterName}}</p>`

Comment: May be here you need to pass input as an attribute to characterName :<p>Character : {{item.character | characterName="input"}}</p>

Comment: Keep in mind http is asynchronous. name is resolved to an empty string. The http call resolves and your console log obviously runs. Getting that data back to the filter is different.

Comment: Thank you Phix. That was totally the issue. I ended up passing in an object with the info from the filter parameters, all working now!